# Почему приложение камеры загружает фото в папку без разрешения на это?

Tags: android

У меня есть `FileProvider`:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/files"/>

</provider>
```

files.xml:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="crime-photos" path="."/>
</paths>
```

также у меня есть лисенер:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent captureImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File mPhotoFile = new File(getContext.getFilesDir(),"photo_name.jpg");
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
        "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider",
        mPhotoFile);
    captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);

    List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureImage,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for(ResolveInfo activity : cameraActivities){
        getActivity().grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName,
            uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

    startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO);

}
```

Всё работает отлично. Я нажимаю на кнопку, затем делаю снимок, потом возвращаюсь на экран с кнопкой, а снимок у меня оказывается в папке `files`. Но потом я попробовал закомментировать следующие строчки:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent captureImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File mPhotoFile = new File(getContext.getFilesDir(),"photo_name.jpg");
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
        "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider",
        mPhotoFile);
    captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);

//  List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities =
//      packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureImage,
//          PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
//
//  for(ResolveInfo activity : cameraActivities){
//      getActivity().grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName,
//          uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
//  }

    startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO);

}
```

Я ожидал, что приложение упадёт после того как я сделаю снимок потому что у активности, которая фотографирует нету `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` разрешения, но приложение после снимка не падает и продолжает работать, а фотография появляется в папке `files`. **Почему?**

Comment: Наверное потому что вы уже дали ему разрешение на этот Uri ранее и оно действует до перезагрузки устройства. И какой-то странный код вы для этого используете - с ним скорее всего будут проблемы при публикации в GP и на Андроид 12+. Обычно разрешение кладут в флаги интента.

Comment: @woesss перезапустил устройство. Результат тот же: все работает без разрешений

Comment: Ах да, забыл. Разрешение даёт провайдер: `android:grantUriPermissions="true"`

Comment: @woesss а какой тогда смысл от метода `getActivity.getUriPermission()` ? Про него в документации написано `To succeed, the content provider owning the Uri must have set the grantUriPermissions attribute in its manifest or included the <grant-uri-permissions> tag.`. То есть разрешения даются при помощи `getActivity.grantUriPermission()` (или при помощи флагов в интентах), а чтобы была возможность это сделать нужно указать атрибут `grantUriPermissions` в манифесте. Иначе для чего эти флаги и этот метод если атрибут всё решает ?

Comment: насколько я понял, где-то внутри android кода у переданного `Intent` вызывается скрытый метод [`migrateExtraStreamToClipData`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#12069), который для определённых action добавляет нужную инфу, для `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` в том числе добавляет [`addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#12172)